# Issue (prob Authentication) Connecting to TFS 2008 via a Website

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I've written a website to display certain tasks and bugs in TFS to our sister company.

It works fine on my machine ... but not deployed.

In live the exception at the bottom `"Work Item Store is null"` is always thrown ...

Can anyone assist please?

```
ICredentialsProvider credentials = new MyCredentials("myusername", "mydomain", "mypassword");

var tfsProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsURL), credentials);

tfsProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

var wis = (WorkItemStore)tfsProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

if (wis == null) throw new Exception("Work Item Store is null");
```

And my MyCredentials class ...

```
public class MyCredentials : ICredentialsProvider
{
    private NetworkCredential credentials;

    #region ICredentialsProvider Members

    public MyCredentials(string user, string domain, string password)
    {
        credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);
    }

    public ICredentials GetCredentials(Uri uri, ICredentials failedCredentials)
    {
        return credentials;
    }

    public void NotifyCredentialsAuthenticated(Uri uri)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958(VS.90).aspx) example work for you?

Comment: nope, but thanks for looking. gave up in the end and wrote a program to email them a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 0):

You have connection problem, it's works fine on your machine, because your machine access TFS Server, but your machine which contains web site deployed is not connected to your TFS server.
Connect to the same domain two machines (Network problem, or ensure that your Firewall configured on TFS accept your deployment machine)